# How do I fix wampserver problem with restoring theme changes?

Tags: wordpress

A few months ago I was working on a wordpress theme on wampserver localhost. today I wanted to check it out (I hadn't used it in a while) but wampserver was having some problems. I made a copy of www folder, then re-installed wampserver and copied the contents of www folder but I can't access the database on Localhost. I get the following error: The theme directory "twentynineteen" does not exist.

I don't know why it needs this theme as it is not the theme I'm using. anyway, I downloaded this theme and copied it to wp-content/themes just to get access to wordpress dashboard. My plugins were in place but none of my pages. I went to appearance/themes and activated my own theme yet again, none of my pages were there.

I did a system restore and repeated all this again with no avail.

how can I restore my changes?

Comment: Reinstalling will have destroyed your databases. Did you have a backup?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reasons why you are getting the error could be that, the theme you were working on was relying on an active plugin that is now deactivated/faulty. And also, did you backup the database before you did the re-install?

Comment: I updated and activated all plugins again but nothing changed. Unfortunately I didn't backup the database, I just copied www folder, assuming everything I'll need is in there. 
The thing is, not only my own changes are gone, but the the whole theme is empty. the default version had lots of sample pages etc.